# angularjs: dynamically create btn-grp

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

a backend defined datatypes, which I should render dynamically in angularjs. The backend might define "sex is enumeration, values male and female".

```
    {
  'name': 'sex',
  'type': 'enum',
  'options': ['female','male'],
  'wert': 'male'
}
```

I can quite easily use a select:

```
<select ng-model="wert" ng-options="value for ( key,value) in  options"></select>
```

But would prefer a button group like

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="wert" uib-btn-radio="'male'">male</label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="wert" uib-btn-radio="'female'">female</label>
</div>
```

Now I try to have those buttons dynamic...

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-repeat='option in options'>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="wert" uib-btn-radio="'{{option}}'">{{option}}</label>
</div>
```

And I fail. Looked quite straight forward to me. But why does the dynamic button group not work out? Seems not to be connected to my scope?

I'm probably not grasping some fundamental angular concept here?
The code is to be put in a directive, but that's probably not related to the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `{{}}` interpolation with the values

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-repeat='option in options'>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="model.wert" uib-btn-radio="option">{{option}}</label>
</div>
```

Other thing I wanted to point out is, you need to define model to follow `Dot Rule`so that will ensure binding will work in correct way. The reason behind you should go for `Dot Rule` is, you have defined `ng-model` inside `ng-repeat`, so that would not available in outer context(`ng-repeat` does create new child scope which is prototypically inherited from it current running controller).

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tKXTlOGwjKbYbFuogk1A?p=preview)

Comment: That has been very helpful, thank you. I got it working now.
However, I'm going for a directive here and created a [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/AsobFrjqRDspdZyGGCz6) myself.
Does your comment about the bindings still apply or would you consider my code to be a valid solution? Right now I don't see a reason to add a controller.

Comment: I don't understand, what was your question?